# AG-Grid nested vs. grouped columns

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

Is it possible to do nested columns instead of grouped? What i mean is that grouped columns are all considered on the same 'level', that is they 2 columns in different groups cannot have the same name. But i need the same column name to appear in multiple groups. We're building a quoting system and the top level would be a product like: the first group is Book Display, 2nd group is Warehouse Racking, etc. Underneath that top level, at the sub-level would be the factories quoting that item. and most of the time it will be 880% the same factories in multiple top-level groups. but if i name a sub column in group 1 the same as a sub-column in group 2, then the values are automatically linked/synchronized. Is there a way to name them the same but have unique values?
Thanks,
Albert